# scala netty codec when calling to Facebook

Tags: facebook, scala, playframework, netty, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_45).  I have an endpoint which makes calls to Facebook to validate Facebook oauth tokens passed to us from our clients.

We asynchronously call to both a homegrown RESTful database service and to https facebook graph api.  In other words, we're calling to two systems simultaneously.  Intermittently, we're getting the exception below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ￆBﾇﾹￋﾸS
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseDecoder.createMessage(HttpResponseDecoder.java:104) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:143) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:127) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:109) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:90) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
2013-11-20 16:55:27,175: ERROR [lt-dispatcher-2]                    application - An unexpected error occurred
```

I am aware of this post to stackoverflow: [Send multiple asynchonous requests on a Netty client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825573/send-multiple-asynchonous-requests-on-a-netty-client).  Although they get a similar error, their code is doing much more complicated bootstrapping, so I think the solution for me will be different. Here is our code:

```
      def getUserInfo(token: String): Future[FacebookUserInfo] = {

        val futureResponse: Future[Response] = WS.url(fbUrl + mePath).withQueryString("access_token" -> token).get()
        futureResponse.map {
          response => parseFacebookUserInfoResponse(response)
        }
      }

      def parseFacebookUserInfoResponse(response: Response): FacebookUserInfo = {
        Logger.debug("Got response code:" + response.status)
        if (response.status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
          val json: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
          val jsonResult: JsResult[FacebookUserInfo] = json.validate[FacebookUserInfo]
          jsonResult.fold(
            valid = {
              success => success
            },
            invalid = {
              error => throw new FacebookResponseException("Invalid Response received.")
            }
          )
        }

        else if (response.status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
          throw new FacebookTokenException(response.json.as[FacebookError].message)
        } else
          throw new MyException(response.body)
      }
```

What is the best way to fix this problem?  Can I switch the default http client and use Apache HttpClient, for example?  Do I need to update the codec?  Do I need to upgrade/downgrade netty?

Comment: We have narrowed this problem down to a problem with our network proxy.  We are only able to reproduce the problem while going through the proxy.  In production we don't use this proxy and we are changing our test environments to not use the proxy.